# Discord Bot Embed returning "Cannot send empty message"

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I've been reworking my help command, which includes making a new Discord Embed but whenever I try to run the command, it crashes to console with

DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message

I've tried remaking the embed (using [this tool](https://leovoel.github.io/embed-visualizer/) as all its embed were made using this) and looking over it multiple times with nothing at least obvious to me that would cause the error.

My code:

````
module.exports = {
    
    name: 'help',
    description: 'Get help on anything from commands, to what the bot does! just not your homework..',
  syntax: '<Command>',

    execute(client, message, args) {
    const footerTxt = require('../config.json')
       const Embed = {
        "title": "HELP SEYMOUR! THE BOT IS ON FIRE!",
        "description": "Get help on anything from commands, to what the bot does! just not your homework..",
        "color": 9442302,
        "footer": {
          "icon_url": message.author.displayAvatarURL,
          "text": footerTxt + " | No mother it's just the northern lights"
        },
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "Arguments",
            "value": "<> is optionable,\n[ ] is required. \n ```<Command>```"
          },
          {
            "name": "...Or is the bot actually on fire?",
            "value": "<> is optionable,\n[ ] is required. \n ```<Command>```"
          }
        ]
      };
      message.channel.send({ Embed });
}};
````

It is using Discord.JS v12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per usual, it's always the little things one can tend to overlook.
The issue was being caused by missing parentheses in the `message.author.displayAvatarURL`

Making the final code be:

````
    
    name: 'help',
    description: 'Get help on anything from commands, to what the bot does! just not your homework..',
  syntax: '<Command>',

    execute(client, message, args) {
    const {footerTxt} = require('../config.json');
       const Embed = {
        "title": "HELP SEYMOUR! THE BOT IS ON FIRE!",
        "description": "Get help on anything from commands, to what the bot does! just not your homework..",
        "color": 9442302,
        "footer": {
          "icon_url": message.author.displayAvatarURL,
          "text": footerTxt + " | No mother it's just the northern lights"
        },
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "Arguments",
            "value": "<> is optionable,\n[ ] is required. \n ```<Command>```"
          },
          {
            "name": "...Or is the bot actually on fire?",
            "value": "Join the [support server!]( )"
          }
        ]
      };
      message.channel.send({ Embed });
}};
````

Answer (score 0):

```
"text": footerTxt + " | No mother it's just the northern lights"
```

make it into

```
"text": `${footerTxt}` + " | No mother it's just the northern lights"
```

Might work the code